# Qt Widget with SVG image and ui elements

Tags: qt, user-interface, svg

In a C++ Qt6 desktop application I would like to display a schematic drawing of an industrial process (which I have in SVG format), overlayed with some ui widgets, like radio buttons and combo-boxes, that represent configurable parameters.

It looks like this can be achieved with `QSvgRenderer`, but there is a problem:
the rendered svg will not be theme-aware.

Is there any way to modify the colors used by this renderer, without parsing and manipulating the SVG myself to edit the color values?
We can assume that all SVG elements are the same color.

Alternatively, can I do something else with my SVG schematic, that *does not involve manually drawing it again* e.g. in `QPainter`, but still accomplishes my original goal?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve? Do you mean for example that you have a monochrome SVG and you want to render it with either white or black color depending on whether you have a light or dark theme?

Comment: Yes, pretty much that. In the end I decided to just parse and edit the svg, it turned out to be easier than I had thought.